# Return to the place of POST

Tags: php

Please, if someone have idea how to do it...
I have created blog where are many post. Each of the post having 'like', 'not like' and 'comments' (as on the many websites of posts).
When I click on 'like'(is in html part inside of element form) of one of the post by the form element I submit POST. Then in php of the same file I increase value of 'like' in database. This value is by echo shown in the proper post updated from database.
The trouble is by doing this update I am not returning to place of increased 'like'. How to go back where I submit POST?
I have seen for example in Instagram when I click 'like' there is no move from the place, staying on the same one where click was made.
Thanks a lot for let me know...

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "amoscaguias_db");

    if(!$conn) {
        echo "<h3>No connection to database</h3>";
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST['increase-btn'])) {
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
        $value = 0;
        $stmt= $conn->prepare("SELECT very_like FROM blog_data WHERE id=? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $post_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $result_1 = $row['very_like'];
        $result_1 = $result_1 + 1;

        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE blog_data SET very_like=$result_1 WHERE id=$post_id");
        $stmt1->execute();
        
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
            integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>blog_php_mysql</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($query as $q) { ?>
                <div class="col-12 post">
                    <div class="card post-card mt-5">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail post-card-image" src="imgs/<?php if(!empty($q['image'])) { echo $q['image']; } ?>" alt="<?php if(!empty($q['image'])) { echo $q['image']; } ?>">
                        <div class="card-body post-card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $q['title']; ?></h5>
                            <hr class="mx-auto">
                            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $q['content']; ?></p>
                            <hr class="mx-auto">
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="col-3 post-footer">
                                    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                                        <button type="submit" id="increase" class="increase_btn" name="increase-btn"><i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up"></i></button>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $q['id'];  ?>" />
                                    </form>  
                                    <span><?php echo $q['very_like'] ?></span> 
                                    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                                        <button type="submit" id="decrease" class="decrease_btn" name="decrease-btn"><i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-down"></i></button>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $q['id'];  ?>" />
                                    </form>  
                                    <span><?php echo $q['dont_like'] ?></span> 
                                    <a href="#" class="post-comments">Comments</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script> 
        <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paragraphs would make your wall of text much easier to read ;)

Comment: Usually you do not use form submissions for such things but JavaScript to just send a request in the background

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it:

1. Common and pretty way: Make an XHR request via javascript to the separate action (endpoint) on the backend, where you will extract data from the POST array, update the value in the database and return response in JSON format, which you can parse easily and set a new value. Also, sometimes there is the approach to increment likes via javascript before the backend will send an acknowledgment about the successful update - it's because likes are not so much important data.
2. Less common and a bit ugly way: you may add an anchor link on each post.
   When you hit the 'like' button, you should send additional data, which includes the way to get this anchor link on the backend. After the backend successfully updates the value, you should redirect to the previous page with an anchor point to the liked post, so you will "return to the same place", because the browser will automatically scroll the page to the block with that anchor.

Comment: Thanks Daria, I'll follow the first suggestion. BR Jozef